# Ожидание пользователя

Tags: java, swing

Есть код:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0, i < 5, i++)
        waitForUser();
}

private void waitForUser() {
    // какая-то логика

    // включаем слушателя, в остальное время он нам не нужен
    listener.setOn(true);

    while (true) {
        // если у слушателя новое событие
        if (listener.hasNewEvent()) {
            doSomething();
            if (someCondition)
                break;
        }

        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // выключаем слушателя
    listener.setOn(false);

// какая-то логика
}
```

Это метод класса с основной логикой, вызывающий слушателя из другого класса. В принципе он делает всё, что мне нужно, а именно:

1. Слушатель работает только в определенный момент работы программы.
2. Как только появляется какое-то событие, это событие обрабатывается.
3. Если все нужные действия с событиями завершились - программа продолжает свою работу.

Что мне не нравится:

1. Прокручивается совершенно ненужный цикл, он сделан только для того, чтобы ждать новое событие, что уже реализовано в `Listener`, но непонятно как продолжить программу после того, как все условия выполнены. Как реализовать этот функционал без цикла? (вертится какое-то решение в голове, но никак не приходит).
2. Побочное. `sleep` мне совершенно не нужен, но если его нет (или нет sout или другой работы), `while` просто не работает. Почему?

Comment: Поясните какая связь между меткой `swing` и вашей проблемой? Возможно вы забыли что то упомянуть?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов в моем случае `Listener` непосредственно связан со `swing`. И возможно именно в коде самого слушателя надо что-то изменить. А как я читал, нужно ставить как можно большее количество меток, т.к. у многих "стоит фильтр, и таким образом Вам быстрее ответят".

Comment: вы дрелью лечите зубы дракону через задницу. Не "слушатели" должны постоянно опрашивать поставщика, а поставщик должен сказать "слушателям", что появилось новое событие. Тогда вообще никаких циклов не будет. Сейчас напишу ответ с примером.

Comment: Хотя не, лень, вот почитайте: http://habrahabr.ru/post/120643/ не идеальный солюшен, но поможет понять. А вообще, почитайте про паттерн наблюдатель.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов не понял о чем Вы. Слушатель стандартный, на клик мыши. В его код я не лез, своего наследника не создавал. Мне не важно как он опрашивает. Мне важно дождаться от него события, обработать это событие, и если меня устроит как оно обработалось, продолжить работу дальше до тех пор, пока опять не понадобится дожидаться события от пользователя.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов ок, почитаю.